# Bokeh - How to get whiskers into foreground

Tags: python, bokeh

Hoi,

I am in the process of making a couple of bar-graphs with bokeh using vbar. Furthermore I added whiskers as error-bars and this all worked quite well, but my whiskers show up in the background of the bar graph and I cannot find the attribute, where I can specify this.

I imagine this has to be specified in either add_layout or in Whisker.

```
p.vbar(x=dodge('genes',  0.25, range=p.x_range), top='100uM', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#e84d60", legend=value("100uM"))
p.add_layout(
    Whisker(source=source, base=dodge('genes', 0.25, range=p.x_range), upper="top_100uM", lower="bottom_100uM")
)
```

Am I blind, or does this option not exist?

Cheers,
Sebastian

Answer (score 3):

So, as soon as I post this, I find the answer:

```
p.add_layout(
Whisker(source=source, base=dodge('genes', 0.25, range=p.x_range), upper="top_100uM", lower="bottom_100uM", level="overlay")
```

level="overlay" is the answer, if anybody is searching for the same thing!